# Loop, to send Outlook mail from DAO recordset, not cycling through entire table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to send emails from Outlook 2010, using a specific email account (NOT the default).

Emails are based on a static template that pulls data from a table (senders_table) for the To, Subject, and a few variable fields within the email body.

The code is not cycling through all of the records in my table.  Emails go out through the specified account and with the proper data pulled from the table but stops after the first record.

```
Private Sub test_Click()

'You must add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook Library
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String
Dim stremail As String
Dim strsubject As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Senders_Table")
With rs

    If .EOF And .BOF Then
        MsgBox "No emails will be sent becuase there are no records assigned from the list", vbInformation
    Else
        Do Until .EOF

            stremail = ![email]
            strsubject = ![address]
            strbody = "Dear " & ![name] & "," & _
              Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Some kind of greeting" & ![address] & "!" & _
              "  email message body goes here"

            .Edit
            .Update
            .MoveNext

        Loop

    End If
End With

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = stremail
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = strsubject
    .Body = strbody

    .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your Send Email code inside the loop so that you send an email out for each record. Something like this:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Senders_Table")
With rs
    If .EOF And .BOF Then
        MsgBox "No emails will be sent becuase there are no records assigned from the list", vbInformation
    Else
        Do Until .EOF
            stremail = ![email]
            strsubject = ![address]
            strbody = "Dear " & ![name] & "," & _
                      Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Some kind of greeting" & ![address] & "!" & _
                      "  email message body goes here"

            '.Edit
            '.Update

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With OutMail
                .To = stremail
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = strsubject
                .Body = strbody

                .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
                .Send
            End With            
            .MoveNext
        Loop

    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I have Query2 with Fields [email];  [Address];  [Name].

I know this is a old thread but I haven't been able to find any code that doesn't make the security message popup. Hopefully this helps someone.

```html
Sub SendEmailFromQuery()


'You must add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook Library
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String
Dim stremail As String
Dim strsubject As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query2") ''add your query here
With rs

If .EOF And .BOF Then
MsgBox "No emails will be sent becuase there are no records assigned from the list", vbInformation
Else
Do Until .EOF

    stremail = ![email] ''Query2 Fields [email];  [Address];  [Name]
    strsubject = ![Address]
    strbody = "Dear " & ![Name] & "," & _
              Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Some kind of greeting" & ![Address] & "!" & _
              "  email message body goes here"


On Error Resume Next
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = stremail
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = strsubject
    .Body = strbody

    .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    .Send
        End With
            .MoveNext
Loop

'On Error GoTo 0

If Not rs Is Nothing Then
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End If

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End If
End With
End Sub
```